# Recursively reverse an array of strings

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

Create and return a new array that is a reversed copy of the array passed as a parameter.

The code I have is the following. I am stuck on the algorithm? This was an exam question but the exam is now over.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Q4_ArrayReverse
{
   public static String[] reverse( String[] in )
   {
      String[] out = new String[ in.length ];
      reverse( in, out, 0 );
      return out;
   }
   ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   //
   // Given an input array, an output array and an index,
   //    copy the element at the index offset of the input array
   //    to the appropriate reversed position in the output array.
   //    i.e. in[ 0 ] -> out[ n - 1 ]
   //         in[ 1 ] => out[ n - 2 ]
   //            etc.
   //    After doing the copy for index, recurse for index + 1
   //    Be sure to quit when you get to the end of the array.
   //
   //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   static void reverse( String[] in, String[] out, int index )
   {







   }
```

Comment: Well, break it down into its components.  In recursion, there always needs to be a terminating condition.

Comment: `Q4_ArrayReverse` is a hateful class name that doesn't match the Java naming convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second (currently blank) method, you will want to swap elements at indexes `index` and `in.length - index - 1` when putting them in the new `out` array. Then of course you want to do the same for `index + 1`, unless you are at the middle of the array in which case you're finished and can return.

```
if (index == array.length / 2)  // i.e. 1 position past the middle
    return

out[index] = in[in.length - index - 1];
out[in.length - index - 1] = in[index];

reverse(in, out, index+1);
```

Comment: if (index == in.length)  // i.e. 1 position past the middle
       return;
     out[out.length - (index + 1)] = in[index];
 
     reverse(in, out, index+1);         It turns out this was enough, not sure why array.length/2 is not necessary.